# Why is the vertical size of these matrices different?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, matrices, size, vertical-spacing

I'm having some problems with the vertical size of these two matrices, as shown with the following MWE code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{upgreek}

\begin{document}

%\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{1em}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{\abovedisplayskip}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{\belowdisplayskip}
\setlength{\jot}{3ex}

\begin{align}
    A &=
    \left[ \begin{array}{c}
        \phi \\[3ex]
        \displaystyle{\frac{\boldsymbol{\upsigma} \cdot \mathbf{p}}{E + m}} \: \phi
    \end{array} \right]
    \\
    B &=
    \left[ \begin{array}{c}
        \displaystyle{\frac{\boldsymbol{\upsigma} \cdot \mathbf{p}}{E - m}} \: \chi \\[3ex]
        \chi
    \end{array} \right]
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Preview:

[image]

Matrice B is shorter than A, why? I would like to make both matrices of exactly the same size.  How?

Using the **bmatrix** environment doesn't help.

Comment: Add a `\mathstrut`  to each of the single char cells

Comment: What is this?  Could you be more specific?

Comment: It is basically a symbol with zero width but the height and depth of a `(`, phi and xi does not have the same depth

Comment: I've found that adding that command inside the fractions (top part only) solves the issue.

Comment: So it's the same as \vphantom{(}, right?

Comment: Something like that

Comment: Using `\begin{align}
A   & = \begin{bmatrix}
        \phi \\[2ex]
        \dfrac{\boldsymbol{\upsigma} \cdot \mathbf{p}}{E + m} \: \phi
    \end{bmatrix}   \\[2ex]
B   & = \begin{bmatrix}
        \dfrac{\boldsymbol{\upsigma} \cdot \mathbf{p}}{E - m} \: \chi  \\[2ex]
        \chi
        \end{bmatrix}
    \end{align}`  matrices as far as I see have equal size.

Comment: I just noticed that using \\\[3ex] (instead of \\\[2ex]) still gives the same vertical problem.  Something is weird here!

Answer (score 1):

With `tabularray` you can set row height:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{upgreek}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{amatrix}{+b}{
    \begin{+bmatrix}[
        rowsep=0pt,
        rows={ht=6ex},
        column{1}={leftsep=4pt},
        column{Z}={rightsep=4pt}
        ]
        #1
    \end{+bmatrix}%
}{}  


\begin{document}
    
    %\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{1em}
    \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{\abovedisplayskip}
    \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{\belowdisplayskip}
    \setlength{\jot}{3ex}
    

\begin{align}
    A &=
    \begin{amatrix}
        \phi \\
        \displaystyle{\frac{\boldsymbol{\upsigma} \cdot \mathbf{p}}{E + m}} \: \phi
    \end{amatrix} 
    \\
    B &=
    \begin{amatrix}
        \displaystyle{\frac{\boldsymbol{\upsigma} \cdot \mathbf{p}}{E - m}} \: \chi \\
        \chi
    \end{amatrix} 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]